# How to insert variable into <img> src parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to generate QR code on my webpage with a data (id) I get from web service. I can not figure out how to insert a javascript variable as a part of `<img>` src parameter.

As you can see I can change the src using myFunction (AFTER button clicked). But I do not know how to insert id variable to the initial page load (to replace ID1_GOES_HERE at the end of img line).
Please help!

Here is a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>        
</head>
<body>

<script>
var id1 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";

function myFunction(){
    var id2 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";
    document.getElementById('qr_img').src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl="+id2;
}
</script>

<img id="qr_img" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl=ID1_GOES_HERE"/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to change the src of qr_img?

Comment: I want to add id1 content to the end of src param so that the API would generate QR code with this string

Comment: try wrapping in the ().      document.getElementById('qr_img').src("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl="+id2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a button click handler, just call the function from your script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>        
</head>
<body>

<script>
var id1 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";

function myFunction(){
    var id2 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";
    document.getElementById('qr_img').src = document.getElementById('qr_img').src + id2;
}

myFunction();
</script>

<img id="qr_img" src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl="/>
<button>test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The click handler is used to capture the button click event, and do something at that time.  That's not what you want, so remove the button click handler.

At the end of the `<script>` element, simply call `myFunction()` to do what it's intended for.

If you wanted to run the script after the entire document and all of its dependencies were loaded, you could do this:

```
<script>
var id1 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";

function myFunction(){
    var id2 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";
    document.getElementById('qr_img').src = document.getElementById('qr_img').src + id2;
}

document.onload = myFunction();
</script>
```

For this simple case, you probably don't actually need a function at all, and the body of `myFunction` can simply be placed inline, like so:

```
<script>
var id1 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";
var id2 = "41c0236f-ed21-4182-be3d-26513078f704";
document.getElementById('qr_img').src = document.getElementById('qr_img').src + id2;
</script>
```

The function would be useful if you had more logic involved, and needed to organize (or modularize) it.

Comment: Thanks for your extended reply. But what should I put at the end of src parameter initially (right now there is "ID1_GOES_HERE"? Basically script would overwrite what was there before. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @AlanKhabitsov Actually, you can completely remove the "ID1_GOES_HERE" and just append the value to it.  I've updated the answer to show how to do that.  The code appends `id2` to the existing `.src` property, which works if you leave off the "ID1_GOES_HERE" from the original HTML.  The Javascript code does replace the value from HTML, so you *could* just write the entire thing as Javascript and use `src=""` for the HTML if you wanted.  Either way works, and if you want an example, I can add that to my answer.

Comment: Michael this is more than enough. I got all the answers. Appreciate your time. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

You could add this to your script below where you declared and set the id1 variable

```
function Window_OnLoad ()
 {

 document.getElementById("qr_img").src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl="+id1;

}
```